# graph enumeration when vertices are 2

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am reading graph theroy. Here author mentions that the number of possible digraphs is truly huge. Each of the V^2 possible directed edges (including self-loops) could be present or not, so the total number of graphs is 2^V^2.
For undirected graphs the number is given by 2^(V(V+1)/2).

For V =2 we have 8 undirected graphs and 16 digraphs.

My question , can any write all combinations for V =2 asuming vertices are "a" and "b". I tried but not able to find all. For example in directed {empty}, {a}, {(a,a)}, {(b,b)}, {b}, {(a,b)}, {(b,a)},  {(a,b), (b,a)} I came up with 8, but according to formula above we should get 16

Comment: This belongs on [math.se], not SO.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a table containing binary indicators of whether each directed edge from the set `{(a, a), (a, b), (b, a), (b, b)}` appears:

```
0 0 0 0 -- {}
0 0 0 1 -- {(b, b)}
0 0 1 0 -- {(b, a)}
0 0 1 1 -- {(b, a), (b, b)}
0 1 0 0 -- {(a, b)}
0 1 0 1 -- {(a, b), (b, b)}
0 1 1 0 -- {(a, b), (b, a)}
0 1 1 1 -- {(a, b), (b, a), (b, b)}
1 0 0 0 -- {(a, a)}
1 0 0 1 -- {(a, a), (b, b)}
1 0 1 0 -- {(a, a), (b, a)}
1 0 1 1 -- {(a, a), (b, a), (b, b)}
1 1 0 0 -- {(a, a), (a, b)}
1 1 0 1 -- {(a, a), (a, b), (b, b)}
1 1 1 0 -- {(a, a), (a, b), (b, a)}
1 1 1 1 -- {(a, a), (a, b), (b, a), (b, b)}
```